# Calculated column: If this than that, with a calculation

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a column named Soort. It has 3 stringvalues. One of them is Brandstof.
There are 2 other columns: AantalKm and Km-vergoeding. They are both numbers fields.
And there is a KostenBrandstof column. This is a calculated field (number).

The value in this field has to be: If Soort=Brandstof, then AantalKm*Km=vergoeding.
Otherwise it can be 0.

So, it tried several things like this:
=IF([Soort]="Brandstof";[AantalKm]*[Km-vergoeding],0)

But that does not work. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mix of semicolons and commas in your formula. Depending on your locale settings, you must stick with one of them.

Based on your column names and values I would pick commas:

```
=IF([Soort]="Brandstof",[AantalKm]*[Km-vergoeding],0)
```

If this gives the error "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.", swap the commas with semicolons and try again.

Comment: You are right. I mixed up the semicolons and commas. The formula that worked for me is: =ALS(Soort="Brandstof";AantalKm*[Km-vergoeding];0)

I need to use semicolons. Thanks